# Looking for External link Manager in Sitecore to declare URLs in one common place and reuse them

Tags: link-manager

I am looking for the option to maintain external links in common location and refer through out the pages.

*For example if my site uses link [www.xyz.com/redirect](http://www.xyz.com/redirect) in 100 pages , I will declare it in one master/common location and refer it to that 100 places.
In future , If I change this URL to [www.abc.com/redirect](http://www.abc.com/redirect) it must impact those 100 places. I shall not go and edit in 100 places.*

Unfortunately, I could not find any thing as such.. Please let me know if it is possible as similar to Image library.

I have added the custom library class as attached in the screen shot, and my sitecore.config code added is

```
 <linkManager defaultProvider="custom"><providers>
      <add name="custom" type="Indivirtual.Shared.Utilities.CommonUtil.CustomLinkProvider,Indivirtual.Shared.Utilities.CommonUtil"  addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageLocation="filePath" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" lowercaseUrls="true" languageEmbedding="never"/>
    </providers>
  </linkManager>
```

getting the error as :
**Could not resolve type name: Indivirtual.Shared.Utilities.CommonUtil.CustomLinkProvider,Indivirtual.Shared.Utilities.CommonUtil (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).**
[image: Custom library class added as shown]

Comment: Create a template with general link field and add the item of that template in global section and use that global item in all the places where you want that link.

Comment: Do you have SXA installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution that wouldn't require customizing any sitecore dialogs would be to create all the external links in a common folder so that the editors can select them from rich text editor or general links by using Insert Internal Link. For this you would create a new template that contains a Link field:
[image]

This way you'll also know in the content editor where each of your external links are referenced:

[image]

The next step would be to create a custom link provider by overriding the `GetItemUrl` method and you would generate the links only for the external link items created in `Global/External Links`

```
namespace CustomLibrary.Links
{
   public class CustomLinkProvider : Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider
   {
      public override string GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item,
         Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions options)
      {
         if (item.TemplateName == "Link Item")
        {
            Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField linkField = item.Fields["Link"];

            if (linkField != null)
            {
                return linkField.Url;
            }
        }
         /*else return the default url generated by Sitecore*/
         return base.GetItemUrl(item, options);
      }
   }
}
```

The above code will work for versions until 9.3. In later versions you will have to create a `CustomItemUrlBuilder` class and override the Build method, please take a look at the examples posted https://cmsclub9.wordpress.com/2020/12/15/take-control-over-sitecore-links/ and  https://adapty.com/blog/sitecore-9-3-custom-link-provider/

You can use this config to apply your custom provider and set the appropriate properties to match your current linkprovider settings:

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="custom">
   <providers>
      <add name="custom" type="CustomLibrary.Links.CustomLinkProvider, CustomLibrary"  addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageLocation="filePath" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" lowercaseUrls="true" languageEmbedding="never"/>
   </providers>
</linkManager>
```

Comment: Thanks @Cristi for the answer,  I am using Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519), I could not find an option to add external links. As per your reply , I understood it should be available in my version. Can you share the screen shot or steps to the external links under the Global folder ?

Comment: The external links are basically simple sitecore items that contain a link field and the link provider will read the external link from that field. I updated the answer to include the Link template and also the code for the link provider.

Comment: hi @Cristi thanks for clarification, I tried , but my breakpoint is not hitting the CustomLinkProvider class. Do I need to do any additional configuration

Comment: Could you add some details on how you have patched the CustomLinkProvider in your config?

Comment: my sitecore.config section will look like below after patching:

Comment: <linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="always" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="true" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false"/>

Comment: (continue) <add name="sitecore" type="Indivirtual.Shared.CommonUtil.CustomLinkProvider, Indivirtual.Shared.Utilities.CommonUtil" addAspxExtension="true"
  alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="never" languageLocation="filePath"
  shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
    </providers>
  </linkManager>

Comment: Hi @Cristi  , I am getting an error:Could not resolve type name: Indivirtual.Shared.Utilities.CommonUtil, Indivirtual.Shared.Utilities (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).

Comment: I have edited the answer with the config patch. can you verify if your break point is getting hit in your provider class? Your error might be related to not specifying the namespace correctly or not having the code deployed.

Comment: hi @Cristi, no luck still, I have posted more details in the below answer, pls have a look and advise. It may help you to identify the issue.

Comment: Please edit the original question instead of adding as answer. Can you try instead of Indivirtual.Shared.Utilities.CommonUtil to set Indivirtual.Shared.Utilities? I think that is your assembly name. Make sure your assembly is also present in the bin folder.

Comment: hi @Cristi, its worked !!! great !! just one more question, I am just worried about the impact on the other places for the website.. since I changed the type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" to type="Indivirtual.Shared.Utilities.CommonUtil.CustomLinkProvider,Indivirtual.Shared.Utilities".. Can you tell me if it break or impact any other areas or any advise to test any areas , our website is big ?

Comment: It won't impact the other functionality in anyway because at the end of your customUrlProvider you have the line return base.GetItemUrl(item, options); which calls the standard sitecore provider. Please make sure to mark the question as answered and also move your text to the question :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort @Cristi.. it really helped me !!